Why interacting of two guards leads to infinite redirection loop in Angular 18?
I've got routes '/' and '/auth'. The logic is that NOT logged in users can access ONLY /auth page, while logged in users CAN'T access it.
So, I've made two guards and for some reason I get infinite loop between them.
I've set up routes like this:
app.routes.ts:
    {
        path: 'auth',
        canActivate: [OnlyUnauthorizedGuard],
        children: [
            { path: '', component: AuthComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        data: {
            allowedRoleIDs: [UserRole.Customer, UserRole.Owner, UserRole.Admin, UserRole.Root]
        },
        canActivate: [RoleGuard],
        component: MainComponent,
    },

My guards are:
role.guard.ts:
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate { 
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }  

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        console.log('Triggered RoleGuard');
        const allowedRoles = route.data['allowedRoleIDs'] as number[];
    
        return this.authService.user$.pipe(
          map(user => {
            console.log('user', user);
            if (user === null) {
              console.log('Redirecting to /auth since user is null');
              this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
              return false;
            }
    
            if (user && !allowedRoles.includes(user.roleID)) {
              console.log('Redirecting to /404');
              this.router.navigate(['/404']);
              return false;
            }
    
            return true;
          })
        );
    }
}`     

onlyUnauthorized.guard.ts:
export class OnlyUnauthorizedGuard implements CanActivate { 
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        console.log('Triggered OnlyUnauthorizedGuard');
        return this.authService.user$.pipe(
          take(1),
          map(user => {
            console.log('user ', user);
    
            if (user) {
              console.log('User is logged in so redirecting to /');
              this.router.navigate(['/']);
              return false;
            }
    
            console.log('Allowed');
            return true;
          })
        );
      }
    }
`    

How I get user data:
auth.service.ts:
export class AuthService { 
  private _userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(null); 
  user$ = this._userSubject.asObservable();  
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.loadUser();
  }

  private loadUser() {
    this._loadingSubject.next(true);
    this.http.get<User>('/auth/getUser').pipe(
      tap(user => {
        this._userSubject.next(user)
        console.log(user)
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        this._userSubject.next(null);
        return of(null);
      }),
      finalize(() => this._loadingSubject.next(false))
    ).subscribe();
  }

  get user() {
    return this._userSubject.value;
  }
}`     

On a page I've got strange error:
PM [vite] Internal server error: Page /auth/getUser did not render in 30 seconds.
I don't see a request to /auth/getUser on a network tab in browser.
There are such logs in Docker when access /auth page (there are no logs on a console tab in browser) :
`
2024-10-28 00:26:06 Triggered RoleGuard
2024-10-28 00:26:06 user null
2024-10-28 00:26:06 Redirecting to /auth since user is null
2024-10-28 00:26:06 Triggered OnlyUnauthorizedGuard
2024-10-28 00:26:06 user  null
2024-10-28 00:26:06 Allowed
2024-10-28 00:26:06 Triggered RoleGuard
...`

It seems that for some reason even if OnlyUnauthorizedGuard returns true a redirect to / happens.

If the user is null and you access the root path /, the RoleGuard redirects to /auth, and then once allowed, it tries to redirect back to / again, causing an infinite loop.
Adjust the guards to prevent them from causing a loop. Use take(1) in both guards to ensure they complete the observable chain properly then make sure the user is loaded before the guards are triggered. Consider initializing your user state to undefined and handle the logic once it's resolved to null or a user object and ensure you don't use navigation inside the guards directly. Instead, return a URL tree.
RoleGuard
    export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate { 
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }  

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | UrlTree {
        console.log('Triggered RoleGuard');
        const allowedRoles = route.data['allowedRoleIDs'] as number[];
    
        return this.authService.user$.pipe(
          take(1),
          map(user => {
            console.log('user', user);
            if (user === null) {
              return this.router.createUrlTree(['/auth']);
            }

            if (user && !allowedRoles.includes(user.roleID)) {
              return this.router.createUrlTree(['/404']);
            }

            return true;
          })
        );
    }
}

OnlyUnauthorizedGuard
export class OnlyUnauthorizedGuard implements CanActivate { 
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | UrlTree {
        console.log('Triggered OnlyUnauthorizedGuard');
        return this.authService.user$.pipe(
          take(1),
          map(user => {
            console.log('user ', user);

            if (user) {
              return this.router.createUrlTree(['/']);
            }

            return true;
          })
        );
      }
}

try to add loading state to handle UI feedback while the user data is being fetched.
